# Mostrar alerta al hacer click a un checkbox, seleccionándolo con querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

Lo único que quiero hacer es que al hacer click en cualquiera de los `checkbox` salte una alerta. Con `querySelectorAll` no me funciona, ahora si hago un `querySelector`, me funciona pero solo la primera.

```js
var chekes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

```
  <div id="checks">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cheke" id="caracteres1" checked/>
    <label for="vehicle1"> ABC</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cheke" id="caracteres2" checked/>
    <label for="vehicle2"> abc</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cheke" id="caracteres3" checked/>
    <label for="vehicle3"> 123</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cheke" id="caracteres4" />
    <label for="vehicle3"> #$&</label>
  </div>
```

```js
chekes.onchange = function () {
     alert("hola");
     }
```

Probé también con `getElementsByClassName` pero no funciona tampoco.

Comment: Te falta especificar un poco lo que buscas, quieres que se muestre la alerta en cualquiera de los checkbox?

Comment: Hola David si, al hacer click en cualquier checkbox.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es entendible que pase eso porque `querySelector` devuelve el primer elemento que encuentre mientras que `querySelectorAll` una lista.

Al ser una lista, necesitas programar lo que quieres que suceda con cada uno de sus elementos.

Supón que tienes un arreglo con números y quieres que se aumente en uno cada uno. Para ello puedes usar un ciclo:

```
arreglo = [4, 8, 1]
for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){
    arreglo[i]++
}
```

Lo mismo sucede con `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma sencilla es detectando que elemento es el que detona el evento, esto mediante el elemento padre o contenedor, ejemplo:

```js
let checks = document.querySelector("#checks");

checks.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  alert(`Hiciste click en el Check con id: ${event.target.id}`)
});
```

```html
<div id="checks">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="caracteres1" checked />
  <label for="vehicle1"> ABC</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="caracteres2" checked />
  <label for="vehicle2"> abc</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="caracteres3" checked />
  <label for="vehicle3"> 123</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="caracteres4" />
  <label for="vehicle3"> #$&</label>
</div>
```