# appendChild genera un error hay alguna explicación?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Estoy estudiando la templates HTML, y quiero agregar 5 imágenes dinámicamente con javascript, junto con sus atributos src, alt y el figcaption. El problema es que cuando trato de agregar las imagenes, usando $cards.appendChild($fragment) para hacer una sola incersión al DOM me dice que appendChild no es una función porque pasa esto?

código javascript:

```js
const $cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards");
const $template = document.getElementById("template-card").content;
const $fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

const cardsContent = [
  {
    title: "Tecnologia",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech",
  },
  {
    title: "Animales",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals",
  },
  {
    title: "Arquitectura",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch",
  },
  {
    title: "Gente",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/people",
  },
  {
    title: "Naturaleza",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature",
  },
]

cardsContent.forEach((el) => {
  $template.querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", el.img);
  $template.querySelector("img").setAttribute("alt", el.title);
  $template.querySelector("figcaption").textContent = el.title;

  let $clone = document.importNode($template, true);
  $fragment.appendChild($clone);
});

$cards.appendChild($fragment); // aqui se genera el error
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <template id="template-card">
        <figure class="card">
            <img>
            <figcaption>

            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </template>

    <script src="templates-html.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Me gustaría que me ayudaran a encontrar la razón del problema, para poder solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mostrar alerta al hacer click a un checkbox, seleccionándolo con querySelectorAll](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/548503/mostrar-alerta-al-hacer-click-a-un-checkbox-seleccion%c3%a1ndolo-con-queryselectoral). `$cards` es una colección. No puedes usar funciones que usarías con elementos individualmente sobre ella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes pequeños errores, el principal de ellos, es el que te señaló @Mateo en los comentarios, al hacer `querySelectorAll` retornas una colección de elementos, esta colección no tiene la función `appendChild`, ya que esta función es de UN elemento en particular.

Otras detalles los dejo comentado en el código

```js
//const $cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards");
const $cards = document.getElementById("cards");

//A buenas primeras esto sobra, solo crea un paso adicional
const $fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


const $template = document.getElementById("template-card").content;

const cardsContent = [
  {
    title: "Tecnologia",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech",
  },
  {
    title: "Animales",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals",
  },
  {
    title: "Arquitectura",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch",
  },
  {
    title: "Gente",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/people",
  },
  {
    title: "Naturaleza",
    img: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature",
  },
]

cardsContent.forEach((el) => {
  $template.querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", el.img);
  $template.querySelector("img").setAttribute("alt", el.title);
  $template.querySelector("figcaption").textContent = el.title;

  let $clone = document.importNode($template, true);
  
  $cards.appendChild($clone);
  //$fragment.appendChild($clone);
});
//$cards.appendChild($fragment);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Te falta este div !-->
    <div id="cards"></div>
    
    
    <template id="template-card">
        <figure class="card">
            <img>
            <figcaption>

            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </template>

    <script src="templates-html.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me servio mucho. Seguiré estudiando sin parar para poder así como tu, ayudar a personas nuevas en este campo.